# What's (really) the difference between fruit and vegetables?

Tags: vegetables, fruit, language

I was wondering what's (really) the difference between fruit and vegetables. Obviously I can name different fruits and vegetables, but if you ask me what's really the distinguishing factor, I wouldn't know.

Things that I think may be the difference are:

- Taste: sweet or not
- Historical reasons
- Whether it is mostly eaten raw or cooked/baked

But for all of the above there seem to be some fruits/vegetables, for which it isn't clear under which category they fall. So, what's the difference between them?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Nix v. Hedden, 149 U.S. 304 (1893) is one ruling on the matter.

Comment: Just to double check, are you asking about the botanical definition (by which things like peppers, eggplant, and squash are fruits) or the culinary one (by which they're vegetables)? I'm not wild about answers/discussion rehashing all that, claiming the botanical definition is the one true definition, etc.

Comment: "Knowledge is knowing that a tomato is a fruit. Wisdom is not putting it in a fruit salad." - Miles Kington

Comment: If you want to answer, please post an answer, not a comment.

Comment: (@Jefromi) Rhubarb is a nice example in the opposite direction; pumpkins (fruit) may be used in sweet or savoury dishes (pie, soup)

Comment: This could also fit in the English Language SE. Interestingly, German has, in addition to the more botanical "Frucht" (fruit), the more food related "Obst" (old English *offet[t]*).

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider Es ist die gleiche auf Niederländisch (meine Muttersprache): "vrucht" (en: fruit, de: Frucht) und "fruit" (en: fruit, de: Obst). :) Ich habe nur "Obst" gelernt, wenn ich Deutschunterricht hatte. Dank für Ihren Kommentar. (Entschuldigen Sie bitte mein schlechtes Deutsch.)

Comment: @Jefromi To be honest, I didn't knew there is a difference between them when I asked this question.

Comment: [Disguised Queries](http://lesswrong.com/lw/nm/disguised_queries/) and the related posts are the solution to 99% of questions of this type.

Comment: @Kevin Okay, so it's nice to learn of the botanical definition, but given your mention of sweetness, it sure seems like you're asking about the way people use the terms in common speech to talk about food (the culinary sense), where peppers, eggplant, and squash are vegetables?

Comment: @eipi10, I've used tomato in a fruit salad before now. It has a lot of flavour compounds in common with strawberries, which is why strawberries can substitute for tomato in recipes like gazpacho. And if you look at the Flavor Bible you'll see lots of fruits listed as going well with tomato and each other.

Answer (score 44):

There is no real black and white definition of that difference, because where the line is drawn varies from crowd to crowd.

> Botanically speaking, a fruit is a seed-bearing structure that develops from the ovary of a flowering plant, whereas vegetables are all other plant parts, such as roots, leaves and stems. By those standards, seedy outgrowths such as apples, squash and, yes, tomatoes are all fruits, while roots such as beets, potatoes and turnips, leaves such as spinach, kale and lettuce, and stems such as celery and broccoli are all vegetables.
>
> The outlook is quite different in culinary terms, however. A lot of foods that are (botanically speaking) fruits, but which are savory rather than sweet, are typically considered vegetables by chefs. This includes such botanical fruits as eggplants, bell peppers and tomatoes.

You can find the whole article [HERE](http://www.livescience.com/33991-difference-fruits-vegetables.html), including this nice graph that I think nicely illustrates things.

[image]

Comment: The US's classification of tomatoes as vegetables was actually [decided by the US Supreme Court](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nix_v._Hedden) due to the implications of import tariffs.  I wouldn't be surprised if the food industry is keeping it that way (so they can claim ketchup as a vegetable).  I'm personally of the opinion that grocery store tomatoes are vegetables, while correctly grown tomatoes are fruits.

Comment: I believe something similar happened in EU - a law/directive passed to classify what everubody thought was one thing to the other.  Not sure it's the same case, but there was also a problem with carrots and juice - since the EU-definition stated that juice could only come from fruits.

Comment: That diagram's a little misleading, since it could be taken as suggesting that the tomato is the only common botanical fruit that's a culinary vegetable. Peppers, aubergines/eggplants, cucumbers, courgettes/zucchini and all other squashes also fit into that category.

Comment: And there are examples of the opposite; the rhubarb stem is considered a fruit rather than a vegetable in culinary terms.

Comment: That's a decent definition, but there are obvious problems with it, as pointed out by the answerer.  Corn are the actual seeds, themselves, how does that qualify?  Vegetable, I guess, but then what about peas?  Also seeds, unless you are eating snow or snap peas, which includes the pods, which all come from the fertilized flower.  Squashes and pumpkins are definitely the seed pods, as are all the varieties of peppers, etc.  Ugh.

Comment: Given that the OP didn't actually know about the botanical definition, it might be worth clarifying that it's not the one used in common speech, and the culinary one is. If you send someone to the store to buy fruit, they're never going to come back with eggplant. (Or tomatoes, unless they're being a smartass and want to get to say "*technically* they're fruit.")

Comment: @BaardKopperud: well, in the case of tomatoes the Supreme Court classified what everyone thought was one thing, to be the same thing they thought it was, a vegetable. "Everyone" in this case being, "everyone except botanists, who didn't invent either the word 'fruit' or the word 'vegetable' and therefore have no especial right to define it, and some lawyers acting on behalf of tomato-importers hoping to avoid tax" :-)

Comment: I considered just editing your answer to add some of the kinds of things I was pointing out, but decided that that'd be pretty aggressive editing, so I just wrote [an answer of my own](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/a/73430/1672). Feel free to take some ideas from there if you want to edit, though!

Answer (score 16):

All of your observations are correct - both the distinguishing factors and the fact that there are foods whose belonging to a category is unclear.

The reason behind this has nothing to do with cooking and everything to do with human cognition. Humans organize the information in their world in categories, which together build "folk taxonomies". For some reason, the prevailing opinion is that the categories in folk taxonomies work like mathematical sets, while the empirical data shows that they do not.

In school, we are taught that categories have a definition, and things either fulfill the definition, or don't. The definition is a bit like a boundary - if you define category X as "all natural numbers below 10", you know which numbers fall inside X and which fall outside.

In reality, all categories we use in everyday life are structured around *prototype members*. There are elements which feel like they truly represent the category, and other elements are more or less similar to the prototypes. This builds a core of elements which clearly belong, and others on the fringes of a category which might or might not belong, depending on how you want to argue.

Now I don't know of any research identifying which are the prototype elements of the categories "fruit" and "vegetable", or which are the important qualities which have to be partially or fully filled to be considered for membership in one of both categories. Taste is the only one I have seen given by food historians, who say that fruit played the role of candy before we learned to refine sugar, so the category depended more than what it is good for (a sweet treat, ready-to-eat) than on what it contains. Thus many botanical fruits became culinary vegetables due to lack of sweetness, but practically no other plant part became a culinary fruit, as the other parts do not have enough sugar concentration. But I am sure that if cognitive scientists have looked into the matter, they will have uncovered more criteria and will have measured whether a pepper or a potato is more prototypical of being a vegetable.

Bottom line, it is all convention. You will never find a strict definition.

Comment: Sweet potatoes would seem to be the obvious example of something that's sweet and even sometimes used in desserts but not generally considered a fruit.

Comment: @Jefromi yes, that's exactly how categories work. If it is good enough by one criterion, but less so by others, it feels like it belongs less to the category (category belonging is gradual, not binary). In other cases, where there is no competing category, this might be sufficient to view the element as an unusual representative of the category. For example, a white cherry is still considered a cherry, because there is no other category which it fits better. But because a sweet potato fulfills "vegetable" criteria to a greater degree than "fruit" criteria, it does not count as fruit.

Comment: Well, I was sort of responding to the "practically no other plant part became a culinary fruit, as the other parts do not have enough sugar concentration" - in this case, there's plenty of sugar concentration, but it's left out for other reasons.

Comment: If this answer intrigues you, I highly suggest "Women, Fire and Dangerous Things" by George Lakoff.  It was our textbook when I took classification (a library science course).

Comment: Another interesting grouping by convention is fish. Biologically the category "fish" does not exist because any grouping of branches of evolution that include fish must also include all four limbed animals including rats, frogs, birds and humans.

Comment: @Jefromi: Potatoes are never fruits. They are tubers. In the biological category where the definition of fruit is concrete (seed bearing product of pollination of flowers) the groupings are fruits, tubers, legumes etc. Biologically potatoes are tubers while wheat and rice are fruits.

Comment: @slebetman This answer is about the *culinary* notions of fruits and vegetables, not the botanical notion, and my comment was a response to one specific part of it, which raised the possibility of other plant parts being deemed culinary fruits then said it didn't happen due to lack of sweetness. I'm fully aware of the biology.

Comment: @Jefromi: Yes, my point is THERE IS NO CULINARY NOTION OF FRUIT. Fruit is a botanical notion and it overlaps with our culinary grouping called "vegetable" -- that's what the answer basically says. Fruit is not a culinary grouping. Vegetable is not a botanical grouping. So the notion of "fruit" and "vegetable" may overlap in the case of tomatoes.

Comment: @slebetman There most certainly is a culinary notion of fruit. For example, apples are a culinary fruit and eggplant is not, despite being a botanical fruit. It's not a well-defined category, but the category exists, and that's what this answer says. And... maybe don't shout?

Comment: @slebetman yes, fish behaves like any other category. A really interesting categroy would be one which does not, a categroy with a firm definition and binary membership, which is also used that way in everyday life (when these categories exist, they tend to be postulated by somebody, and rarely match reality).

Comment: @slebetman: tubers (or rather, tuber-bearing plants) are not a clade, just like animals commonly called fish are not a clade. So if on the one hand you say fish is "not a biological classification" simply because it isn't a clade, you could say the same of tubers, or in the case of animals you could say the same of "eyes". Cladistic taxonomy of species isn't the same thing as the labelling of biological structures. It's still true that "vegetable" isn't a botanical grouping, except perhaps as an old-fashioned name for the version of Plantae that (mistakenly, by modern views) included fungi.

Comment: @Jefromi - I'd heard one of the reasons sweet potato is a vegetable is that it is substantial and nutritious enough to be a main course food, while fruit is usually lighter.  On the other hand, I have actually heard a few votes for sweet corn to fall on the "fruit" side of the equation, since it's high in simple sugars, low in other nutrients, doesn't fit in with grains (though flint corn does), and also - corn syrup.  One person just said the sugar content means it's more *like* a fruit than a vegetable, another flat out compared it to a berry - little bubbles of sweet juice, basically.

Answer (score 14):

The [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fruit) distinguishes between *botanical* fruits and *culinary* fruits. (Interestingly, both German ("[Obst](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obst)" vs. "Frucht") and [Spanish](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fruta) ("Fruta" vs. "Fruto") have distinct terms for these.)

To quote:

> In culinary terminology, a fruit is usually any sweet-tasting plant
>   part, especially a botanical fruit; a...); and a vegetable is any savory or less sweet
>   plant product.

(Both the German as well as Spanish Wikipedia articles support this *loose* definition.)

And the [vegetable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vegetable) article says:

> The term vegetable is somewhat arbitrary, and largely defined through
>   culinary and cultural tradition. It normally excludes other food
>   derived from plants such as fruits, nuts and cereal grains, but
>   includes seeds such as pulses. The original meaning of the word
>   vegetable, still used in biology, was to describe all types of plant,
>   as in the terms "vegetable kingdom" and "vegetable matter".

Answer (score 11):

There's a bit of confusion here because there are two senses of the word "fruit": the botanical sense with a more precise definition (plant parts with seeds), and the common everyday culinary usage with no precise definition (mostly sweet plant things).

---

In a culinary sense, i.e. talking about food, among chefs or just in common speech, there is no strict definition of fruit, and no completely precise delineation between fruit and vegetables. Sweetness and how it's eaten play a big part in defining fruit, as you've noted, and culinary fruits are mostly botanical fruits that meet those criteria, but that doesn't form a perfect definition. See [rumtscho's excellent answer](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/a/73397/1672) for more on how categories like this are (and aren't) defined. Vegetables, then, are basically everything from plants *besides* the fruit, also excluding grains.

This is the sense of "fruit" you'll generally hear. If you ask someone to organize a grocery store produce section, to go to the store and buy some fruit, or to put fruit in each lunch bag, they'll tend to use this sense of fruit/vegetable. So apples, oranges, and bananas will be fruits, while spinach, peppers, cucumbers, and beets will be vegetables.

But other things are less clear. For example, if you cook green plantains (starchy, not sweet, can be used much like potatoes) and ask someone if they're a fruit or a vegetable, you're pretty likely to get a response along the lines of "well, they're like bananas, so they must be fruit, but they're not sweet." And you could hear differing opinions on whether fresh corn is a vegetable or a grain.

---

Then there's the botanical sense, i.e. talking about parts of plants. In that sense, there's a strict definition: fruit is the seed-bearing structure of the plant. Other parts of the plant then have their own names; you'd talk about stems and leaves and roots, not vegetables.

You'll hear this sense in botany, such as "the fruit of the maple tree are called samaras or whirlybirds". It's similarly used in gardening, as in "my zucchini and tomato plants are bearing plenty of fruit".

Note that while it makes plenty of sense to talk about fruit in this context, it doesn't really make a lot of sense to talk about *fruit vs vegetable* in this context. You're not going to look at a tomato plant and say "it has a lot of fruit, and the vegetable parts look healthy too." You might talk about your garden as having fruit and vegetable sections, but then you're coming back to the culinary sense.

---

Unfortunately, when the two senses come together, people can sometimes make pretty wild claims. Perhaps because the botanical definition is scientific and precise, while the culinary one is unscientific and fuzzy, people sometimes portray the botanical definition as the "real" one. This leads to statements like "[technically](https://xkcd.com/1475/), fruit has seeds, so tomatoes are fruit."

But it's best to simply consider the context. Generally you'll be clearly talking about food, or clearly talking about plant anatomy. And if you're talking about food, most foods have uncontroversial categorizations, even if explaining *why* is difficult.

So if you want to be a smartass, by all means, when someone asks for a piece of fruit hand them a tomato and say "technically...". But if you want to just enjoy food and not get into pointless arguments, just use a bit of common sense and avoid trying to force the two senses of "fruit" together.

Answer (score 6):

Botanically, a fruit has seeds.

A vegetable is the edible portion of a plant. Vegetables are usually grouped according to the portion of the plant that is eaten such as leaves (lettuce), stem (celery), roots (carrot), tubers (potato), bulbs (onion) and flowers (broccoli).

A fruit is the mature ovary of a plant. So a tomato is botanically a fruit but is commonly considered a vegetable. According to this definition squash, pepper and eggplants are also fruits. Then there are seeds such as peas which are also considered vegetables.

As a food they often get reclassified.

One factor is the amount of complex versus simple carbohydrates. Think simple - sweet - sugar. Medically complex carbohydrates are preferred as you don't spike. Nutrition is off scope for the site. What I am saying is if you group by simple versus complex it explains a lot of the common exceptions.

Tomato, cucumber, or pepper are botanical fruits that are commonly thought of as vegetables.  They are all relatively low in simple carbohydrates < 2/3 of the carbohydrates are sugar.

An avocado is very low in sugar and is commonly considered a vegetable.

And apple is actually low in simple carbohydrates but most people would hold with fruit.

A sweet potato is sweet but it is still relatively low in sugar.

Almost 1/2 the carbohydrates from carrot is sugar but I would still call it a vegetable.  But I would call carrot juice a fruit juice.

Answer (score 3):

If you're confused by the fruit and vegetable differentiation you can remember a rule of thumb - a fruit has seeds while vegetables don't.

Comment: This is the botanical definition, not the culinary one. (And while it worked out this time, you might want to avoid using humor novels as sources for answers?)

Comment: The stated question is  "What's (really) the difference  ...  but if you ask me what's really the distinguishing factor, I wouldn't know."   +1

Comment: By this definition, not only tomatoes but also e.g. cucumbers, zucchini, pumpkins and eggplants are fruits. Also, plant breeders have managed to come up with plenty of [seedless fruits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seedless_fruit). When did you last see a banana with seeds?

Comment: Perhaps they are fruits and, like the tomato, are just as misunderstood. I also don't get why a botanical answer wouldn't be as acceptable as a culinary one. I would've thought that a scientifically based answer (despite the source and validity of this specific answer) would outweigh whatever some random chefs/cooks/etc have decided to call it over the years. Also, it's an interesting twist to include GMO produce into this debate.

Comment: The OP is pretty clearly not asking about the botanical definition; they mention sweetness as a dividing line, and *tons* of botanical fruits are not sweet and widely considered to be vegetables. It's not that it's *wrong*, it's just not what was asked about.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen: Yesterday. Of course, in my country the varieties of banana we eat are closer to the wild banana than the commercial version available elsewhere (yes, varieties - there are about 3 species (yes species, not breeds) that are commonly sold but around a dozen total)

Comment: @IlmariKaronen Last time I saw a banana with seeds was... the last time I ate a banana.  Of the ordinary yellow supermarket variety.  You know those little black specks you find throughout the core of the fruit?  *Those are seeds.*  They've just selectively bred them into a variety that produces tiny seeds that don't cause any problems with chewing and swallowing the fruit.  "Seedless" oranges and grapes are very similar.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44490/discussion-between-jefromi-and-paparazzi).

Comment: So, I don't remember this from Hitchhiker's Guide, and I can't find the quote (or even little pieces of it) anywhere on the internet, let alone associated with Douglas Adams. Maybe I'm missing something, but... where did this come from?

Comment: "Seedless" means without MATURE seeds, not without any seeds whatsoever.

Comment: Since you didn't respond, I've gone ahead and removed the misattribution of your statement. Utility of the answer aside, it's not good to mislead your readers.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it really matters, does it. Botanically, as already said, a fruit is any seed containing capsule (drupe, berry, nut and so on), or one that would carry seeds without the intervention of Man, so a pine cone is a fruit, along  with the usual plums, apricots, courgettes (zucchini depending where you are) tomato and so on. Roots, shoots, stems, leaves, and tubers  are not fruits, but are of plant origin, and many of these will be described as vegetables. How cooks decide on a description is probably entirely down to whatever they're being used for - does the addition of mango or grape to a leafy salad make it a fruit salad? Clearly, it does not. As far as cooking goes, there are definitely blurred lines between 'vegetable' and 'fruit', many often being used in both savoury and sweet dishes. So unless you feel like creating a new term or two, you're  stuck with describing anything of plant origin that's served as a dessert as 'fruit' and anything served as savoury as 'vegetable', regardless of its botanical definition.

Answer (score 1):

Even the botanical definition is a bit confusing as a 'true fruit' relates to a very species type of structure and does not include, for example apples and strawberries.

A good practical definition is that fruits are specific parts of a plant which are produced seasonally  and harvested without harvesting the whole plant or to put it another way fruits are something which is 'picked'.

Clearly a big part of this is down to language, we are discussing this in English and when English developed there was a pretty clear distinction as in medieval north western Europe you had apples, pears and berries and anything else which couldn't run away was a vegetable and  a lot of the confusing cases like tomatoes, peppers, squashes, cucumbers (and related) were either completely unknown or didn't travel well.

In terms of cooking there are some clear differences in their properties. Often fruits have a high moisture content (juice) and as well as being sweet may also be sharp or sour and tend to have more complex and aromatic flavours.

Really it is all about convention and the important thing is to understand the characteristics of a **specific** ingredient

Answer (score 1):

This answer is from a culinary point of view only, but I thought it worth mentioning.

I asked this of a chef I used to work with, figuring he'd know due to his education (CIA) and experience (40+ years), and this was his answer:

> If you only remove the part you actually eat but leave the main part
>   of the plant intact, its a fruit. If you actually cut off part of the
>   main plant or eat the whole thing, its a vegetable.

By this reasoning, fruits would be things like apples, citrus fruits, stone fruits, grapes, cherries, tomatoes, eggplant, peppers, bananas, pineapple, cucumbers, and all manner of squash or berries. Meanwhile vegetables would be things like potatoes, carrots, yams, spinach, lettuce, cabbage, broccoli, cauliflower, turnips, asparagus, jicima, and onions.

Answer (score 0):

A really crude definition: A fruit is something you put in your pudding/dessert or your breakfast; a vegetable is something you put in your dinner.

Apple - goes in cereal and pie --> fruit.
Tomato - goes in pasta and salads --> vegetable.

Of course, this isn't perfect. Pineapple, for example.

This leads to some interesting definitions. In my country, pumpkin is a vegetable, because we roast it and make soup out of it. In North America, it is a fruit, because pumpkin pie is a dessert.